# Filter array list of objects by specific value of key

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have an array list like this  and i would like to get the value of the key "Total" for the Product Name - Leisure 1 but not sure how to search or iterate through an array list of objects in Java spring boot

```
 "priceList": [
      {
        "Total": "10",
        "Stamp Duty": "10",
        "Main Policy": "0",
        "Product Name": "Leisure 1"
      },
      {
        "Total": "10",
        "Stamp Duty": "10",
        "Main Policy": "0",
        "Product Name": "Leisure 2"
      },
      {
        "Total": "10",
        "Stamp Duty": "10",
        "Main Policy": "0",
        "Product Name": "Leisure 3"
      },
      {
        "Total": "10",
        "Stamp Duty": "10",
        "Main Policy": "0",
        "Product Name": "Work 1"
      },
      {
        "Total": "10",
        "Stamp Duty": "10",
        "Main Policy": "0",
        "Product Name": "Work 2"
      }
    ]
```

i tried doing this. I created a function

```
public static <K, V> Stream<K> keys(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
        return map
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .filter(entry -> value.equals(entry.getValue()))
          .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
    }
```

Then i tried to cast my array list to a map and tried to filter through the list to find the exact object but to no avail

```
priceList.stream().map(x -> x.get("Total").toString()).filter(s -> s.get("Product Name") == planHeader).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can i be able to loop through or search through an array of objects and filter by a specific value?

Any help appreciated

Comment: What is the input data type?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala if referring to planHeader it is a string. If referring to priceList is is an Map<String, Object>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `s.get("Product Name") == planHeader`

Shouldn't you be comparing this with equals()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `equals` method to compare strings that are not `==`.
This method checks the actual contents of the string and the `==` operator checks whether the reference to the object is the same.

```java
priceList.stream()
      .map(x -> x.get("Total").toString())
      .filter(s -> s.get("Product Name").equals(planHeader)) // here
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an arrayList, just iterate over it and for each object do the getter to get the total.

```
for (Item i : priceList) { 
    system.out.println(i.getTotal());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess from your post, that you use a data structure like this:
`List<Map<String, String>> priceList`

You really should be using a custom class for you prices. If you want to go with lists and maps, the following few lines might help.

```
        List<Map<String, String>> priceList = readPrices();
        // stream the list
        String total = priceList.stream()
                // filter for the price's Product Name
                .filter(price -> "Leisure 1".equals(price.get("Product Name")))
                // find the first one
                .findFirst()
                // extract the Total from the found price
                .map(price -> price.get("Total"))
                // return null if no matching price found
                .orElse(null);
```

It's OK to access a map with a string key. The map uses `hashCode` and `equals` internally. Nothing to worry about here.